# Finding out commands/menus GUID/ID in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, guid, vs-extensibility

I googled it around but didn't find it. I remember there was a way to click VS2010 buttons/commands/menus in a way it would retrieve me the GUID of the command instead of executing it.

It made extensibility easier, but I can't find it anywhere!

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1.aspx)